# How to declare ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings?

Tags: vb.net, oracle, configuration, system.configuration

hello i'm using visual studio 2008, vb.net and oracle as my db.
this is what i save in my apps.config

```
<appSettings/>
<add key="SMSDW_connection" value="server=abc;database=efg;User ID=**;Password=**;"/>
```

and this is my code for calling the apps.config file :

```
    Dim connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SMSDW_connection")
    Dim sqlConnection As OracleClient.OracleConnection = New OracleClient.OracleConnection(connectionString)
```

but still i got an error which is :

The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

i have add reference System.Configuration and Imports System.Configuration

Comment: Why are you using the `appSettings` section when there's a dedicated `connectionStrings` section available?

Comment: i want to call the apps.setting file if i want to make connection for every page.

Answer (score 0):

The `<appSettings>` node has the closing tag "/" so the `<add` is outside of it.

it should read:

```
<appSettings>
<add ...
</appSettings>
```